How can I split up a string into multiple pieces and place into multiple fields in a mysql table?
I currently get a directory listing from several different hard drives and store each as a text file. Next I merge these files into one single larger text file and then import the text file into a mysql table as so I can retrieve each component from the string (each line of the text file) into the proper fields in my table. Each line is formatted as follows:
Drive:\folderName\fileName.EXT fileSize
example:
C:\example\example.txt  123456
I have been successfully doing this in MS Access for long time. The only problem is in Access, each command must be one at a time.
I wish to use a PHP file to make the whole long process more automated and less prone for error. I am a total newbie coding in PHP and have relied a lot on this wonderful site for the progress I've made so far.
The SQL commands I use in MS Access are:
UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET fileSizeRAW = Mid([pathRAW], InStrRev([pathRAW]," ")+1);

UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET path = REPLACE(pathRAW, fileSizeRAW, '');

UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET path = Trim(path);

UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET fileExt = Mid([path], InStrRev([path],".")+1);

UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET drive = Left(path, 1);

UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET path = REPLACE(path, 'M:\', '') WHERE Left(path, 1) = 'M';

UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET path = REPLACE(path, 'N:\', '') WHERE Left(path, 1) = 'N';

UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET path = REPLACE(path, 'O:\', '') WHERE Left(path, 1) = 'O';

UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET path = REPLACE(path, 'P:\', '') WHERE Left(path, 1) = 'P';

UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET path = Left([path], InStrRev([path],".")-1);

UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET folderName = Left([path], InStr([path],"\")-1);

UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET fileName = Mid([path], InStrRev([path],"\")+1);

UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET flag = 'y'
Where fileExt = 'srt'
or fileExt = 'db'

Delete from DirList_FORMATED
where flag = 'y';

UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET fileSizeGB = (((fileSizeRAW /1024)/1024)/1024);

UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET fileSizeGB = ROUND(fileSizeGB, 3);



Import text file into a table called DirList_RAW (using phpMyAdmin)

using PHP code I have successfully:

I'm able to connect to my DB
Empty a temp table I use to format the string in called DirList_FORMATTED
Insert the pathRAW field from DirList_RAW into pathRAW field in DirList_FORMATED

Next step is retrieving the components of the string pathRAW and storing in the appropriate field, but so far I haven't had much success with.
I have to extract fileSize, fileName, ext (file extension), folderName, and drive (drive letter) from each row and place in appropriate fields in table.
Any help to get me started or point me in right direction would be greatly appreciated :)
my php code so far :
<?php 

// Include the database config file 
include_once 'assets/includes/dbConfig.php'; 

$query = "DELETE FROM DirList_FORMATED";
$conn->query($query);
echo 'DirList_FORMATED emptied <br/>';

$query = "INSERT INTO DirList_FORMATED (pathRAW) SELECT pathRAW FROM DirList_RAW WHERE pathRAW is not null";
$conn->query($query);
echo 'DirList_RAW inserted <br/>';

$query = "UPDATE DirList_FORMATED SET fileSizeRAW = Mid(['pathRAW'], InStrRev(['pathRAW'], ' ' )+1);";
$conn->query($query);
echo 'fileSizeRAW created <br/>';

?>


last line keeps throwing an error about syntax
I've tried multiple variants for the quotes but still no joy :(

I'm having a really hard time following the specific of what you are trying to do, however, if I'm reading it correctly, I think most people would do what you are trying to do in PHP, not SQL. Its not to say you can't or you shouldn't, it is just (arguably) easier to debug these kinds of string-based manipulations that you are performing.

MySQL doesn't have MID, instead you can use SUBSTRING, for start.

You don't put [] around names in MySQL, that's only for SQL-Server or Access. MySQL uses backticks to quote identifiers. You also shouldn't have quotes inside the [], I'm not sure why you wrote ['pathRAW'] instead of [pathRaw].

Chris Haas    ...   Sorry for any confusion, I'm trying to write a php file to execute these steps to accomplish same as the above commands I've been using from SQL window in Access.

+1 to what Chris said. Repeatedly updating a table like this is just going to thrash your disk and make the whole thing perform like a sedated tortoise.

The Mid and InStrRev functions are specific to MS Access and won't work in MySQL. Instead, you can use MySQL's string functions.

IT goldman     Thanks, I'll lookup syntax and start experimenting :)

Sammitch   ....   Thanks for your input.. I haven't experienced any tortoise problems with hard drive. Maybe it being an ssd drive make difference.

@Tim, if that’s the case, I’m not seeing any PHP code for string manipulation, just SQL code embedded in PHP, so I’m not sure where to start. Just so we’re clear, I’m talking zero database until the data itself is perfect.

Study Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question. Provide table structure (#5), text file sample (3-5 rows), desired final data state (#3).

@Chris Haas ... Thank you very much for your response. I have been using Access SQL query design to populate the appropriate fields in my table for a long time until  I recently setup a WAMP server with intentions of making this process easier using php to handle the multiple sql queries. Your comment made me rethink my approach and  realize I should use php instead of SQL commands  to manipulate my string and build my SQL table. I have been using the SQL and Access for so long, I hadn't completely realized the new possibilities using the WAMP & php actually provides. Thanks again

@Tim, you are welcome! I came from the same place 20+ years ago, although ASP Classic + Access, then MSSQL Server. The jump really isn't that big, either, once you get the hang of it. Good luck with this!

A sample.
File to be loaded:
C:\example\example.txt 123456
D:\example2\example2.txt 123456789
E:\example3.data\example3.txt.txt 123456789012
F:\example3.txt 123

Table structure:
CREATE TABLE test (
  id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  drive CHAR(1),
  path TEXT,
  filename TEXT,
  fileext TEXT,
  filesize BIGINT UNSIGNED,
  raw TEXT
  );

Query:
INSERT INTO test(drive, path, filename, fileext, filesize, raw)
SELECT LEFT(raw, 1),
       REGEXP_REPLACE(raw, '^..(.*\\\\)[^\\\\]+$', '$1'),
       REGEXP_REPLACE(raw, '^.+\\\\([^\\\\]+)\\.[^.]* \\d+$', '$1'),
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(raw, '.', -1), ' ', 1),
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(raw, ' ', -1),
       raw
FROM JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(LOAD_FILE('C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.4/Uploads/test.csv') AS CHAR), '\\', '\\\\'), '\r\n', '","'), '"]'),
                '$[*]' COLUMNS (raw TEXT PATH '$')) jsontable;

Result:
mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+----+-------+-----------------+--------------+---------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | drive | path            | filename     | fileext | filesize     | raw                                            |
+----+-------+-----------------+--------------+---------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | C     | \example\       | example      | txt     |       123456 | C:\example\example.txt 123456                  |
|  2 | D     | \example2\      | example2     | txt     |    123456789 | D:\example2\example2.txt 123456789             |
|  3 | E     | \example3.data\ | example3.txt | txt     | 123456789012 | E:\example3.data\example3.txt.txt 123456789012 |
|  4 | F     | \               | example3     | txt     |          123 | F:\example3.txt 123                            |
+----+-------+-----------------+--------------+---------+--------------+------------------------------------------------+


very efficient and elegant SQL solution, with only one issue. I import the text file (which is delimited with quotes and each row in txt file is new row in table) into a table called DirListRAW. The table consists of only one field containing the pathRAW string. If I'm correct, your solution uses a JSON file. I've looked at how to convert my csv file to JSON, but I'm trying to learn the JSON syntax and formatting necessary for your solution to work for me. What would be the changes needed on the CONCAT to change your solution from a JSON to my csv format file as in your example?

@Tim Please read my comment to your question, study provided link, provide needed sample data.

I read your comment, studied the link. I'll continue to hopefully learn how to better use REGEXP but it has a learning curve for sure. The format of the imported csv file and my needed final desired result is in my original post. Thanks again for your time and patience :)
